# Is the ethereum.org/dao contract vulnerable to recursive call attacks?

Tags: solidity, the-dao, evm, dao, vulnerability

Does putting `p.executed = true` after `p.recipient.call()` make this vulnerable to recursive calls?

```
function executeProposal(uint proposalNumber, bytes transactionBytecode) returns (int result) {
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    if (p.executed) throw;

    p.recipient.call.value(p.amount)(transactionBytecode);

    p.executed = true;
```

From [ethereum.org/dao](http://ethereum.org/dao)

Comment: What a terrible system.

Comment: It's not terrible. Ethereum is new and everyone is still learning how to program on it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!
the attacker would have to use a call in his wallets *fallback function* and call the function again so he will be able to detract the money within the same recursion call, before `p.executed = true`.